# Why does it matter whether unary negation or multiplication has a higher precedence

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, operator-precedence

The precedence of operators in VB.NET can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx). It states that the unary negation operator has a higher precedence than multiplication and division.

What would be an example where this makes a difference? I mean, `(-2)*3=-(2*3)`

Comment: Probably a bit off topic for SO but I have answered anyway as it is something that can catch people out if they are not aware of it

Comment: 2*-3 would not be a valid syntax if they have the same precedence (added this as a comment because I don't know if the VB parser has its own precedence rule)

Comment: @adrianm you are incorrect - `2*-3` is perfectly valid syntax

Comment: @adrianm Why not? What could be the operand of `*` if not `-3`?

Comment: When overloading operators, it's important to have precedence to know in which order things will be executed. Also, check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) in mathematics, -3^2 can mean a different things depending on the order of operation.

Comment: @the_lotus Note that I specifically asked about multiplication and division. Yes, I already thought about overloading. However, I am teaching this in the class that will not get to overloading, so I was wondering if I can come up with a less advanced motivation.